# You know where I go, but do you know what I am?

Tags: riddle, word

```
Where I go, everyone knows,
No matter where, I am composed,
My journey there clearly shows.

In a sense, I am made of me,
Just look at me, me on me you see!
You may know what my purpose be,
But overseas, not so easily.
```

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be a

> Letter

Where I go, everyone knows,

> The address is marked clearly on the outside

No matter where, I am composed,

> Letters are composed (written)

My journey there clearly shows.

> Letters are postmarked during transit

In a sense, I am made of me,

Just look at me, me on me you see!

> A letter is made up of individual letters (i.e., letters of the alphabet)

You may know what my purpose be,

But overseas, not so easily.

> The letters are language-specific

Comment: I think what hes looking for on the made of me is more rot13(yrggref znxr hc jbeqf juvpu ner jevggra ba n yrggre) but excellent answer.... it's gotta be it.

Comment: @Z.Dailey - Hayrff gur yrggre'f jevggra ol M-Qnvyrl, gura vg'f cebonoyl nyy ahzoref

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA @Khale_Kitha so true...

Comment: Although the reasoning isn't exactly the intended, this is the answer

Comment: @elmer007: well, I would love to know them. Could you please share them after sometime.

Comment: @me_digvijay It's too long for a comment; do you mind if I edit your answer to include the line-by-line? It's not too different from your answer (because your answer does make sense), it just has a slightly different angle

Comment: @elmer007: Please go ahead and edit the answer:)

Comment: @Z.Dailey Yes, but it worked anyway. The answer is edited for specificity/intention

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be

> a meme (of the [internet variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_meme), not the [more abstract kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme) famously defined by Richard Dawkins).

Where I go, everyone knows,

> Everyone knows that memes go on the internet, have their 15 minutes of fame and then are usually forgotten.

No matter where, I am composed,

> Memes are a form of expression - they are *composed* by people trying to make an artistic or humorous point or a political statement by adding a caption on to an image or animated GIF.

My journey there clearly shows.

> Memes are tweeted, retweeted, emailed, shared on facebook etc. When you come across one you can often trace it back through the sequence of shares/retweets to see where it came from.

In a sense, I am made of me,
Just look at me, me on me you see!

> The word "meme" is made of "me" and "me".

You may know what my purpose be,
But overseas, not so easily.

> If a meme contains a locally-known quote or catchphrase easily understood by people from one culture, its meaning may be lost on overseas readers.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, actually. Unfortunately, it is not the intended solution to the riddle